# Run a SAS macro through a loop and storing the results as a single table

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I need to run a `SAS` `macro` for number of iterations and save the output of the of the each iteration to a single table (each iteration as a row) I know to do this easily from `R`. But I don't have any idea to do the same using `SAS`.

Here is my sample data and code.

```
DATA HAVE;
input yr_2001 yr_2002 yr_2003 area;
cards;
1 1 1 3
0 1 0 4
0 0 1 3
1 0 1 6
0 0 1 4
;
run;

%macro cal_sum(w1,w2);
data wsum;
set Have;
wsum= yr_2001*&w1. + yr_2002*&w2.;
run;
proc means data = wsum mean;
var wsum;
run;
%mend;

%macro res;
%do i=1 %to 2;
%do j=1 %to 2;
%let p1=%eval(&i.*1/2);
%let p2=%eval(&j.*1/2);
%cal_sum(&p1.,&p2.);
%end;
%end;
%mend;

%res
```

The above code prints proc means output for each iteration. But I need to store the results as a table so that each row contain the result of each iteration. Is this possible through SAS?

Thank you

**Update**

My current output is follows:
[image]

I need to store the results into a single table rather than printing the results separately.

Comment: Why do you think you need a macro to do this?

Comment: Your current code is not generating any output datasets at all, so there is nothing to combine.

Comment: @Tom It is generating a proc means output for each iteration

Comment: So there is nothing to save?

Comment: @Tom I have updated my question with my current output

Comment: You want your visual output stacked? That seems useless, you should put it in a data set and combine them into a single data set.

Comment: @Reeza Do you mean combing proc means to a data step? I am sorry I am new to SAS. Just figuring out the efficient ways . Thank you for your help

Comment: What you're showing is displayed results, having that shown in output as individual tables or one table won't really change how you view the data. You're also not tracking which scenario generates which output. If you're interested in efficient methods you really shouldn't be using macro's you should be using a data step as indicated in my first response. It's unlikely that what you're trying cannot be handled there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using macros and moving your loop to the data step. Then you can use PROC MEANS once and save the output to a data set.

```
DATA HAVE;
    input yr_2001 yr_2002 yr_2003 area;
    cards;
1 1 1 3
0 1 0 4
0 0 1 3
1 0 1 6
0 0 1 4
;
run;

data wsum;
    set Have;

    do i=1 to 2;

        do j=1 to 2;
            p1=i*1/2;
            p2=j*1/2;
            wsum=yr_2001*p1 + yr_2002*p2;
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;

proc means data=wsum nway mean;
    class p1 p2;
    var wsum;
    ods output summary=want;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Thank so much for your answer. This is kind of a demo code. I have a complicated macro in the real code. Would it possible to show the answer with a macro also (in addition to this) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very inefficient methodology but this is how you can do this in a macro. Here is a [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Don%27t-Be-Loopy%3A-Re-Sampling-and-Simulation-the-SAS%C2%AE-Cassell/7227dcc6f1367a51e40ae019cde17cef907469b4) that details the flaws in this type of methodology.

- Add weights to data set, so that you can track output to each loop, in data step
- Create data set (not output) from proc means  (`output` statement, `nway` option on proc means)
- Append to a master data set via `proc append`
- Delete intermediary data sets, `proc datasets`, in case a loop goes bad for some reason
- Ensure you delete the master table, `proc datasets`, before running the macro to ensure you start from scratch each time.

```
DATA HAVE;
    input yr_2001 yr_2002 yr_2003 area;
    cards;
1 1 1 3
0 1 0 4
0 0 1 3
1 0 1 6
0 0 1 4
;
run;

%macro cal_sum(w1, w2);
    data wsum;
        set Have;
        wsum=yr_2001*&w1. + yr_2002*&w2.;
        w1=&w1.;
        w2=&w2.;
    run;

    proc means data=wsum noprint nway;
        class w1 w2;
        var wsum;
        %*save output to data set;
        output out=ds_sum (drop=_:) mean=average_wsum;
    run;

    *append to data set;
    proc append base=master_summary data=ds_sum;
    run;

    *drop intermediary tables to keep work library clean;
    proc datasets lib=work nodetails nolist;
        delete ds_sum wsum;
    quit;

%mend;

%macro res;
    %*delete master data set ahead of loops;

    proc datasets lib=work nodetails nolist;
        delete master_summary;
    quit;

    %do i=1 %to 2;

        %do j=1 %to 2;
            %let p1=%eval(&i.*1/2);
            %let p2=%eval(&j.*1/2);
            %cal_sum(&p1., &p2.);
        %end;
    %end;
%mend;

%res
```